# Application with users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing an application where there will be users with specific permissions within the application, I will make available in the saas model, my question is if I should create a project in firebase for each company that use my application or is there any way to control this in the firebase database?

Comment: I couldn't understand how exactly will your app work? Different companies using different data? Or Different companies using the same data?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really the right place to be seeking broad advice on how to build your application.  Consider posting to the firebase-talk google group instead.  Come back to Stack Overflow when you have a specific question with the code you're writing to implement your app.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use custom token claims in order to set different permissions for your users.

In your rules, you can set something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "adminContent": {
      ".read": "auth.token.premiumAccount === true",
      ".write": "auth.token.premiumAccount === true",
    }
  }
}
```

You can then create a custom token with that custom claim for that user using admin node.js sdk:

```
admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid, {premiumAccount: true});
```

You can then send the customToken to your client side app after sign in. Make sure you verify the ID token on your backend and then verify your user meets your permissions requirements:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then(function(result) {
    // User is signed in. Get ID token.
    return result.user.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(idToken) {
    // Send ID token to backend.
    $.post(
      '/setCustomAttributes',
      {
        idToken: idToken
      },
      function(data, status) {
        // Check if custom token is returned.
        if (status == 'success' && data) {
          var json = JSON.parse(data);
          if (json && json.customToken) {
            // User is eligible for upgrade. Set custom attributes on the user
            // via custom token sign-in.
            firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(json.customToken);
          }
        }
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```